# Order column by the first value

Tags: mysql

I've got the following table Foobar that looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+
| ID | Description |
+----+-------------+
| 12 | 307         |
+----+-------------+
| 13 | 308         |
+----+-------------+
| 15 | 312         |      
+----+-------------+
| 14 | 309-310-311 |  
+----+-------------+
```

When I order using **ORDER BY Description ASC** , this Description **309-310-311** will be last one as above. What I would like is to print out all the descriptions in order to be like this

```
307 
308 
309-310-311 
312
```

Comment: Actually works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5f1d/2

Comment: When sorting alphanumeric, as I guess would be the case in a column like that, the sorting will be exactly as you requests. If the sample data you are giving is not the true data I guess you have to change your sample data to better reflect the problem. You might need to look at string function, e.g left() and position()